# Must the top of a sukkah be level?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, sukkot, schach

I saw [this question about a portable *sukkah*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95356/472) and I immediately thought of those pop-up canopies that you sometimes see at picnics and the like.  The canopy has a metal or plastic frame that folds up and a (usually plastic) cover over the top.  I've seen ones where the cover can be removed.

This seems like a reasonable basis for a portable *sukkah* except for one thing: these canopies have a peak in the center (to shed rain).  That would make it difficult to have the *s'chach* level with the ground:

[image]

And *that* made me wonder:
Is the *s'chach* required to be level?
Or is a *sukkah* allowed to have a peaked or pointed roof?

Assume, for purposes of this question, kosher supporting materials and a means of attaching *s'chach* to a slanted frame; I'm just asking about the legality of the shape.

---

(A similar [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62419/472) arises with a *palapa*, a temporary structure with a convex roof but does not question the validity of the slanted roof rather the validity of the structure itself if perched in a place that will destroy the succcah e.g sea shore.)

Comment: I had the same reaction to that question as you did. That said, I think I can top you, depending on how tall he needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10637/170 or, especially, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62419/170

Comment: Certainly if the schach is within 3 tefachim from top to bottom there’s no problem (lavud). The question only applies if there’s more than 3 tefachim.

Comment: @DonielF where do we learn that?  (Sounds like an answer, if this isn't a dupe.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Lavud is a general principle throughout Shas (especially Eruvin and Sukkah) that states that anything within three tefachim of each other is considered as if there’s nothing between them. It’s my own understanding that this would be an application of it - if I had a proper source, it would address above 3 tefachim as well. That said, this is an exact duplicate of the second question which explicitly asks about a convex roof.

Comment: The schach can be slanted as long as it's on a ma'amid and has proper walls. The schach doesn't need to be within three tefachim of the walls as long as the walls have ten tefachim in height(about 70 cm). So yes, it's fine.

Comment: @chachamNisan thanks.  I encourage you to write an answer (ideally citing sources) on the question this is marked as a duplicate of.  That question doesn't yet have an answer about the roof.

Comment: A big issue with such a sukka would be the walls. Material walls are problematic, though some sukkas now come with straps to resolve the issue

Comment: @user613 sometimes zip-lock cable ties can be used to pull them tight, but in this case the whole frame may just get pulled inwards and not stay taut

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is addressed in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 631,10:

> סוכה שאין לה גג כגון שהיו ראשי הדפנות דבוקות זו בזו כמין צריף או שסמך ראש הדופן של סוכה לכותל פסולה ואם היה לה גג אפילו טפח או שהגביה הדופן הסמוך לכותל מן הקרקע טפח הרי זו כשרה. הגה: וצריך שיהיה בה שבעה טפחים על שבעה בגובה עשרה טפחים (טור)
>   A Succah without a flat roof at all e.g the entire walls slant and meet in the middle like a tent, alternatively one wall is slanted against a straight wall is Invalid. But if there was a section of roof flat roof even a Tefach (Hand-breadth )alternatively the slanted wall(s) rested on a vertical wall with a length of a tefach form the ground this is Kosher. Rema: But we need a volume of 7 by 7 tefachim with a height of 10 tefachim within these slanted walls (that have a tefach horizontal roof with sechach or vertical wall).

So yes your gazebo has straight walls much larger than 1 tefach (and the volume of a gazebo is much larger than 7x7x10), so putting the Sechach on the slanted sections of the roof makes it Kosher with 3 walls.

Comment: @loani on the side there are 4 walls over a tefach high read the SA again