# Is fixed wooden diagonal Schach Kosher for a Sucah?

Tags: halacha, sukkah

We visited a family of non-orthodox Jews here in Jerusalem that has a permanent wooden pergola on their large balcony. The roof is a wooden frame with wooden bars about 2x10 cm freely inserted (no screws) *diagonally* at 45º angle in such a way that when the sun rises it shines through the gaps between the bars (no shadow in the Succah), but toward noon the Succah is almost fully shadowed. (similar to the picture below but in the opposite, sun-facing direction)

[image]

Two questions about the Kosherness of such a Succah:

1. As "old Succah" is outlawed, they claim to refresh the bars before Succot by lifting the bars and letting them slip back into their places. Does it constitute a Kosher refreshing?
2. Regarding צילתה מרובה מחמתה - is such a Succah Kosher?

*NB: I'm not gonna see and talk to this family so the question is not personal, I simply never saw such an arrangement for a Shach.*

Comment: @DanF http://www.etsim.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/41-2.jpg

Comment: As long as it was intended to be there for the purpose of shade, which I assume it was, it doesn't need to be "refreshed" - MB 636:3, And the need to refresh it in the first place is only l'chatchila, but b'dieved the sukkah is still kosher - MB 636:4

Comment: Another question to consider is whether they can use wooden bars at all: they might be an issue of גזרת תקרה, depending on the dimensions.

Comment: The refreshing method seems fine as the way it's normally done is simply moving the schach a bit (although, as other comments have noted, it's likely unnecessary). Not sure about the shade question. I remember there's a tosafos that gets into all the trigonometry regarding the height of the walls and the sun's angle at different times of day, but I don't remember if there's anything there that could be applied here (don't have my gemara at the moment). Gezairas tikra is likely an issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must the top of a sukkah be level?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95360/must-the-top-of-a-sukkah-be-level)

Comment: @user There’s quite a few issues here which don’t apply in that case. Voting to leave open.

Comment: @DonielF true, but maybe you can chose to close for practical ruling that should be asked to a rabbi, i mean theres even a picture this is begging to be closed

Comment: @user15464 He’s not asking for himself, nor for the family in question - he’s asking out of curiosity. We can’t gauge the intent behind the question and have to assume what he’s saying to be taken at face value.